# c# Entity Framework - Querying 2 Linked Columns

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have some entities setup along these lines:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}

public class Event
{
    public int EventId {get;set;}
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public virtual Person {get;set;}
}
```

I also have a custom method for pulling from my repository

```
public IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).AsNoTracking();
}
```

I also have a helper to gather query parameters from a GET query.
For instance my Event parameter helper may have a property like

```
public string EventCreator {get;set;}
```

with an example URL of
..../event?eventcreator=tom

The trouble im running into is that i want the EventCreator to match against the full name of the person. If i do my query like this, it works:

```
_repoWrapper.Event.FindByCondition(p => p.Person.FirstName.Contains(filterModel.EventCreator ?? String.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
.Where(p => p.Person.LastName.Contains(filterModel.EventCreator ?? String.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

However, obviously if the query contians parts or all of the first AND last name, this will not match.

What i want to do is something like this, but it doesnt want to work

```
_repoWrapper.Event.FindByCondition(p => String.Format("{0}{1}", p.Person.FirstName, p.Person.LastName).Contains(filterModel.EventCreator ?? String.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Im getting an error like:

```
        Message "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Event>\r\n    .Join(\r\n        outer: DbSet<Person>, \r\n        inner: t => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(t, \"PersonId\"), \r\n        outerKeySelector: a => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(a, \"PersonId\"), \r\n        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Event, Person>(\r\n            Outer = o, \r\n            Inner = i\r\n        ))\r\n    .Where(t => string.Format(\r\n        format: \"{0}{1}\", \r\n        arg0: t.Inner.FirstName, \r\n        arg1: t.Inner.LastName).Contains(\r\n        value: __p_0, \r\n        comparisonType: InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."   string
```

Anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: what about using .Join() and regular expressions?

Comment: Can you elaborate? im new to EF

Comment: the way I work with EF/linq is different, I set up the database, and then, I have some dbContext, and work with the tables or classes directly, what I would do is get the list of objects, and then use .Where(o => o.firstname.Contains(xxx)), and once I have them join them but seeing properly the classes, I think that you should not join them because one should include the other one

Comment: by the way, can you provide an example of what you are after?

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do this with linq alone.. You'd have to first write logic to extract the first and last names from the search terms and compare the columns individually.  You could write some sql to do this which concatenates the columns and compares them but I think performance would not be great (depending on how many rows of course), but EF cannot work out how to write that sql for you... Maybe write a view which concatenates columns and a model for that which you. Just use for searching? (not sure about performance though)

Answer (score 0):

In current state `string.Format` is not translatable to SQL by EF Core. Also `Contains` function is case sensitive and translating `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` depends on provider maturity. But there is `EF.Functions.Like` which can be used for such task.

Omitting your repository filter:

```
var query = _repoWrapper.Event.FindByCondition(p => true);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterModel.EventCreator))
   query = query.Where(p => 
        EF.Functions.Like(p.Person.FirstName, $"%{filterModel.EventCreator}%")
     || EF.Functions.Like(p.Person.LastName,  $"%{filterModel.EventCreator}%"));
```